# Map array of functions

Tags: list-manipulation, array

What is the most elegant way of mapping an array of functions to an array of arguments of the same length? In practice I want to map `{f1,f2,f3}` and `{x1,x2,x3}` to `{f[x1],f[x2],f[x3]}`. Thanks!

EDIT

I should have mentioned that `{f1,f2,f3}` are the solutions of a differential equation:

```mathematica
fsol[t_] = Table[First[f[t] /. NDSolve[{f''[t] + m^2 f[t] == 0,
        f[0] == c[[i]], f'[0] == cp[[i]]}, f[t], {t,0,1}]], {i,1,3}]
```

Then the output is something like

```mathematica
{InterpolatingFunction[t],InterpolatingFunction[t],InterpolatingFunction[t]}
```

When I evaluate `fsol[t]` for some numerical `t` I get a numerical array as a result. With the proposed solutions the argument gets appended at the end, but the `InterpolatingFunction`s are not evaluated at that point.

EDIT 2:

Here is a minimal working example:

```
c = {1, 2, 3};
fsol = Table[NDSolveValue[{f''[t] + f[t] == 0, f[0] == c[[i]], f'[0] == 0}, f, {t, 0, 5}], {i, 1, 3}]
xtest = {1, 2, 3};
```

Then `MapThread[#1[#2] &, {fsol, xtest}]` indeed gives the desired result. The remaining question is, can the same be done with the derivative of `fsol`? `MapThread[#1[#2] &, {fsol', xtest}]` doesn't seem to work, since Mathematica doesn't interpret that as the derivative of the components of the array.

Comment: `MapThread[#1[#2] &, {{f1, f2, f3}, {x1, x2, x3}}]`

Comment: Very helpful, but see comment below.

Comment: Please post an example which `{f1,f2,f3}` are a list of InterpolatingFunction, and what is the relation about `{f1,f2,f3}` and `f` ane why the result should be `{f[x1],f[x2],f[x3]}`?

Comment: @gabo_18 You mention that {f1,f2,f3} are `InterpolatingFunctions` returned by `NDSolve`. In that case you should probably have a look at the alternative `NDSolveValue`.

Comment: A minimal _working_ example would be helpful

Comment: …As to EDIT 2: why not `MapThread[#1'[#2] &, {fsol, xtest}]`?

Comment: Yes that's perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MapThread[Construct, {{f1, f2, f3}, {x1, x2, x3}}]
```

Comment: Very helpful, but see comment below.

Comment: It should still work (all of the suggestions so far should still work). If it's not working, then you need to show more information about your interpolating functions.